# google apps script find value in range and return offset value

Tags: google-apps-script, offset

I'm new to GAS and am trying to replicate some VBA code I wrote in Excel for my punting group so it can be used in a google sheet. The gyst is...

- i have an array of ids on one sheet (transactions)
- i need to find each id within a range on a second sheet (selections)
- if the id is found, then i need to retrieve an offset $$ value
- if the id is not found, then i need to retrieve the value $1
- after all $$ values has been retrieved, i then need to multiply them by each other

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    sel = ss.getSheetByName('selections'),
    trn = ss.getSheetByName('transactions');

function calcPayout(a,b,inv) {
  var data = sel.getRange("B3:B");
  
  // find a in data, then return offset(0,2) as div1
  // find b in data, then return offset(0,2) as div2
  
  return div1 * div2 * inv
}
```

while i'd like to automate it, to work the same as the Excel s/s i created, i'm just as happy to use a UDF, as indicated in the snippet above.

in VBA i used the following to do the same thing...

```js
div1 = trn.Cells(i + 2, 11)  // finds 'a' instead of user entering 'a' 
    div1 = data.Find(what:=div1).Offset(0, 2).Value
div2 = trn.Cells(i + 2, 12)
    If opt2 = Empty Then GoTo calcLegReturn // calcReturn does 'return' calc
        div2 = data.Find(what:=div2).Offset(0, 2).Value
```

Can anyone help me out? If needed [this is a sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OnVURV9xK7sS6_-ZHP85b21VGbAKF6EOHtKTHMUr_SA/edit?usp=sharing) of what the google sheet will look like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by 'offset', but anyway I wrote some formulae in your sheet.

In `transactions` sheet, you can get ID from `B:B` by `=value(right(B3,3))`. Say this in on `I3` and then you can look up that ID in `selections` sheet by `=match(I3, selections!B:B, 0)`. It returns the matching row, so `=index(selections!D:D, match(I3, selections!B:B, 0))` gives you the 'offset'(`D:D` in `selections` sheet). Say this is on `J3` and then you can get payout by `=J3 * product(C3:F3)` in `G3`. Check your sheet to see if this is what you intended.

Comment: thanks for your response. i have updated the formula in the 'payout' column to better represent what i'm trying to do in GAS. as you can see, its a pretty longwinded and messy formula which is why i'm trying to write the google equivalent of VBA to manage this.

Comment: If formula works, why bother GAS? Anyway, in GAS, you can get values by `getRanges()` (`getRange()` is terribly slow, just google it). It gives you a 2-dimension array. Then you can search the array by `for` loop. But I guess writing 10+ lines of code for the job like this is not worthy...

Comment: yes, the formula works but its not practical in the long run. that particular formula repeats itself c. 250 times in the current sheet but will double in the next 12 months. i also have at least 20 other formulae in that spreadsheet that make similar offset calculations. the more times this formula is repeated the bigger (& slower) the spreadsheet is, hence why i want to remove the recurring formulae.

Comment: also, in the main s/s i'm finding the offset of 6 variables as opposed to the 3 variables in the sample... so each formula doubles in size.